# Create a new DataFrame from big DataFrame by group sum of values on my column -Python

Tags: python, list, split

I have a big dataframe with 3 Columns looking like this:

```
date,Currency,price
2010,USD,100
2010,USD,100
2010,EUR,140
2010,GBP,100
.....
```

I want to create a new dataframe only containing sum of price by each currency at the end i will have table with :

```
Currency, price
USD,130000,
EUR,9389893
....
```

I Have a big list of currencies so better not put it on list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a `pd.DataFrame` object, you can do:

```
df[['Currency', 'price']].groupby('Currency').sum()
```

If the `price` column values are not `int`, you'll need to do that conversion with:

```
df['price'] = df['price'].astype(int)  # or float
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I have another question, when I multiply  one column to another column I get SettingWithCopywarning: a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a dataframe do you have an idea how to fix this ?